# ggplot does not display inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this function to plot the city and income. The plotting code works perfectly fine when it is not inside the function. However, when I called it with the function, no graph showed up. Please help! Thanks.

```
graph <- function(x, y) {
  df %>% 
    filter(city == "x", year == y) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(log(income))) +
      geom_histogram()
}
```

I tried to assign the plot to `p` and then add `print(p)`, but nothing showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you take x as a param, but dont use it in your function; you use a hardcoded x to check against city; its likely you get nothing, and so plot empty charts

besides from that, I can set up an analogous construction and see charts just fine; so theres not inherent reason that the plot wouldnt be seen from inside a function like this

Comment: Thank you! That's super helpful! I do wonder though how can I replace the hardcoded x with the parameter x. For example, when I call the function, I don't wanna put "" around city names every time. Any way I can just put the city name and let the function recognize the name should be "" itself?

Comment: Just don't put speech marks, you didn't for y... its no different.